# RPL Setup with Contiki Simple UDP API and Border Router

Tags: contiki

I have a seemingly easy but quite specific question. I have three different node types in my network: a client, an aggregator and the border router (rpl-border-router). There should be a unicast connection between one (or multiple) clients and an aggregator. When the aggregator gets messages of some specific type or when some threshold is reached the aggregator forwards some other message to the border router. The example code of unicast-recevier (aggregator) in the simple-udp-rpl folder creates a RPL DAG the following way:

```
static void create_rpl_dag(uip_ipaddr_t *ipaddr) {

  struct uip_ds6_addr *root_if;

  root_if = uip_ds6_addr_lookup(ipaddr);
  if(root_if != NULL) {
    rpl_dag_t *dag;
    uip_ipaddr_t prefix;

    rpl_set_root(RPL_DEFAULT_INSTANCE, ipaddr);
    dag = rpl_get_any_dag();
    uip_ip6addr(&prefix, UIP_DS6_DEFAULT_PREFIX, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    rpl_set_prefix(dag, &prefix, 64);
    PRINTF("created a new RPL dag\n");
  } else {
    PRINTF("failed to create a new RPL DAG\n");
  }
}
```

However, since the border router creates a RPL DAG on its own, the receiver (aggregator) cannot send messages to the border router. But removing this RPL code from the receiver results in the inability to receive messages from the sender (client). So the problem is probably somehow connected to RPL. The ContikiRPL code is not really well documented and I am struggling to make progress. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea how well supported is inter-DAG routing in Contiki, but in your example having 2 DAGs seems like an overkill. Why not have all nodes in the same DAG? A node can send unicast messages to other nodes in the same DAG, not just the root node.

Comment: I agree. The problem I had (and still have) is that if you use one DAG and the client and the border router are within radio distance, the aggregator won't get the messages from the client. As far as I know, RPL constantly senses the radio to avoid redundancy. So if the aggregator realizes the messages are directly sent to the border router, it discards the packet. What would help me greatly is a possibility to send messages to the border router via unicast (so packets not directly target to the border router won't be picked up), but I can't see an easy way to make that change.

Comment: You sound very confused about what is done at what layer. Rejecting packets not addresses to a node is done by the radio, most likely at hardware level. It's possible to have the radio operate as a sniffer (similar to promiscuous mode) by disabling this hardware address filtering. The rest I did not get - why can't you send unicasts to the aggregator first from all clients and then aggregator sends to the border router?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand that. As far as I know the border-router is in some sense a sniffer because every message within radio distance to the border-router is picked up by it even if it's a unicast message sent to another node. It wouldn't matter much if the unicast message could reach the aggregator anyway, but for some reason it doesn't. And I suspect the reason for this is my aforementioned redundancy avoidance by sensing for equal packets within the network. It seems a bit illogical to me.